# HTML FORM + pureJS Auto multiply script

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a simplified HTML form that I would like to multiply entered amount by 100 and send it with GET method to any endpoint.

Here is my form:

```html
<body>
    <form method="get" action="https://endpoint/purchase.php">
        <input type="text" name="description" value="description">
    <input type="text" name="amount">
    <input type="submit" value="pay">
    </form>
</body>
```

And my Js

```js
var $output = $("#output-value");
$("#input-value").keyup(function() {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
    $output.val(amount*100);
});
```

I'm stuck here, as I don't know how to connect them to send a proper value where I want?

Thank You. That helps a lot, I have another problem, where, in which the URL passed in GET is shortened / cut out?

So below is an original URL

`https://sklep.przelewy24.pl/zakup.php?z24_id_sprzedawcy=88696&z24_kwota=10000&z24_currency=pln&z24_nazwa=test&z24_opis=test&z24_return_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.przelewy24.pl&z24_language=pl&k24_kraj=PL&z24_crc=ca056736&`

I would like to be able to dynamiclly trnasfer z24_kwota (/z24_amount) so my form can transfer the amount as I want.
After tweaking the code above to my needs:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Formularz uproszczony</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    
    </script>
<form id="testForm" method="get" action="https://sklep.przelewy24.pl/zakup.php?z24_id_sprzedawcy=88696&z24_currency=pln&z24_nazwa=test&z24_opis=test&z24_return_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.przelewy24.pl&z24_language=pl&k24_kraj=PL&z24_crc=ca056736&">
  <input type="text" name="z24_kwota" value="Kwota">
  
  <input type="submit" value="zapłać ">
  <script>
        $("#testForm").on('submit', function() {
  var amount = $("#testForm input[name='z24_kwota']")
  var value = parseFloat(amount.val());
  value = value * 100 || 0; // set zero for non number

  if (prompt("Kwota przekazywana do Przelewy24 to: ", value)) {
    amount.val(value);
    return true
  } 
  else {
    console.log('submission aborted, value not multiplied')
    return false;
  }

});</script>
</form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I see that only first part is in the browser adress bar:
'''https://sklep.przelewy24.pl/zakup.php?z24_kwota=2000'''
Can someone tell me why that is, and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

This is common problem, please see browser console (F12) and check for error, you don't have element with ID `#input-value, #output-value` and variable `amount`

if you want to change input name `amount` before submit use `submit` event

```js
$("#testForm").on('submit', function() {
  var amount = $("#testForm input[name='amount']")
  var value = parseFloat(amount.val());
  value = value * 100 || 0; // set zero for non number

  if (prompt("amount value now: ", value)) {
    amount.val(value);
    return true
  } 
  else {
    console.log('submission aborted, value not multiplied')
    return false;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="testForm" method="get" action="https://endpoint/purchase.php">
  <input type="text" name="description" value="description">
  <input type="text" name="amount">
  <input type="submit" value="zapłać z przelewy24.pl">
  </form>
```